# Is there any way of implementing the msvc_typeof in other compilers?

Tags: c++

Looking around on the internet, I found **[this](http://www.nedproductions.biz/blog/implementing-typeof-in-microsofts-c-compiler)** (MSVC typeof implementation). However, I am not sure if I could, and *how* I could implement this in any other compilers, not just for MSVC.

Please note: I am not looking for the `register_type` macro, e.t.c, as I already have implemented that myself.

Code from site:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER>=1400
namespace msvc_typeof_impl {

    struct msvc_extract_type_default_param {};
    template<int ID, typename T = msvc_extract_type_default_param> struct msvc_extract_type;

    template<int ID> struct msvc_extract_type<ID, msvc_extract_type_default_param>
    {
        template<bool> struct id2type_impl;

        typedef id2type_impl<true> id2type;
    };

        template<int ID, typename T> struct msvc_extract_type : msvc_extract_type<ID, msvc_extract_type_default_param>
        {
            template<> struct id2type_impl<true> //VC8.0 specific bugfeature 
            {
                typedef T type;
            };
                template<bool> struct id2type_impl;

                typedef id2type_impl<true> id2type;
        };


            template<int N> class CCounter;

            // TUnused is required to force compiler to recompile CCountOf class
            template<typename TUnused, int NTested = 0> struct CCountOf
            {
                enum
                {
                    __if_exists(CCounter<NTested>) { count = CCountOf<TUnused, NTested + 1>::count }
                    __if_not_exists(CCounter<NTested>) { count = NTested }
                };
            };

            template<class TTypeReg, class TUnused, int NValue> struct CProvideCounterValue { enum { value = NValue }; };

            // type_id
#define unique_type_id(type) \
    (CProvideCounterValue< \
    /*register TYPE--ID*/ typename msvc_extract_type<CCountOf<type >::count, type>::id2type, \
    /*increment compile-time Counter*/ CCounter<CCountOf<type >::count>, \
    /*pass value of Counter*/CCountOf<type >::count \
    >::value)

            // Lets type_id() be > than 0
            class __Increment_type_id { enum { value = unique_type_id(__Increment_type_id) }; };

            // vartypeID() returns a type with sizeof(type_id)
            template<int NSize> class sized { char m_pad[NSize]; };
            template<typename T> typename sized<unique_type_id(T)> vartypeID(T&);
            template<typename T> typename sized<unique_type_id(const T)> vartypeID(const T&);
            template<typename T> typename sized<unique_type_id(volatile  T)> vartypeID(volatile T&);
            template<typename T> typename sized<unique_type_id(const volatile T)> vartypeID(const volatile T&);
}

#define typeof(expression) msvc_typeof_impl::msvc_extract_type<sizeof(msvc_typeof_impl::vartypeID(expression))>::id2type::type
#endif
```

Comment: so your looking for a way to implement RTTI on your own?

Comment: c++11 has `decltype`, before which compilers had various offerings including [`typeof`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) - you haven't said what compilers you're interested in, but if you search for each compiler vendor and 'typeof' and 'decltype' you're likely to find whatever documentation there is.